# Header tags in mat-list material angular5 not working

Tags: angular-material2, angular5

I followed https://material.angular.io/components/list/api but for Header I don't see any difference when header tag level is changed. Changing it to h1, h2 etc doesn't seem to change the font-size. Also, I see that mat-subheader is used in the examples but in the documentation its referred as matSubheader. I tried both but neither worked. Plz advise if someone solved it

```
<h3 matSubheader>Folders</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<mat-list *ngFor="let e of emp; let i = index">
  <h3 mat-subheader>{{e.prefix}}</h3>
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let employees of e.employee; let j = index ">
      <h4 mat-line>{{employees.name}}</h4>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: .mat-subheader, .mat-list .mat-subheader 
{
    background-color: #EAF4FF;
    color: #666666;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
}

Comment: if I have to manually set the font-size then I see no point in using mat-subheader/matSubheader

Comment: by default it has some style you have to add some style if you wish sub-header look differ  as its default state
https://material.angular.io/components/list/examples

it has style :
.mat-list .mat-subheader, .mat-nav-list .mat-subheader, .mat-selection-list .mat-subheader {
    font-family: Roboto,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.mat-subheader {
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 16px;
    align-items: center;
}
that's why it wont effect after you change h1.. h2... h3.. etc.

Comment: @sgowd <h3> and <h3 mat-header> will get you the same results, because mat-header doesn't do anything. It was just the _absence_ of matSubheader that made the difference for you.

Answer (score 1):

When you apply the matSubheader *attribute* to your HTML element, the angular directive will automatically apply the mat-subheader CSS class. Using the matSubheader attribute is the appropriate way to invoke the functionality. The reason it didn't make any difference if you used an h1, h2, or h3 is because Angular Material does apply some styling to this class that includes font-size, color, weight, etc., and so it doesn't matter if you stick the attribute on an h3, h1, or a div, the text will always look the same.

I fully agree that the out-of-the-box styles for this are...underwhelming, so you will need to add your own; this is not such a terrible thing. If you want h1, h2, h3 to have different sizes or styles when they are subheaders in your mat-list, you might try something like this:

```
.mat-subheader {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: green;
}

h2.mat-subheader {
    font-size: 20px;
}

h3.mat-subheader {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```